# Check for build errors in Visual Studio post build step

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am working with a solution containing several projects. There is one otherwise empty "Deploy" project that - in its post build step - does stuff via a small batch script. My issue is that this currently happens even if the build had errors.

I would like to pass an argument to my batch script that prevents any operation on errors. I was expecting something like an errorlevel macro, but could not find anything, neither by poking around or via google.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Using an custom event listening for build errors as suggested by fellow users @displayname and @dlatikay would be sufficient for me, but I'd prefer a solution that does not need to change anything to the IDE itself so it can be passed to other people/systems with less hassle.

Comment: [Does that help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833213(v=vs.100).aspx) ?

Comment: have a look at this: http://einaregilsson.com/stop-build-on-first-error-in-visual-studio-2010. then consider adding all other projects as a dependency to your deploy projects, so that you can be sure it is last in build order.

Comment: @dkatikay, that does seem to be a workaround... gonna try it.

Comment: Any reason why your batch file can't interrogate the build log file to determine if there were any errors?